# Change other cells' values depending on the value of one cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

In Microsoft Office Excel 2010 how would you make another cell change dependant on your current cells value. For example if `A1=C1` then make `B1=D1` or if `A1=C3` then make `B1=D3`.

```
|   |     A    |  B   |     C    |   D   |
|:-:|:--------:|:----:|:--------:|:-----:|
| 1 | Person 3 | Steve| Person 1 |  Dan  |
| 2 |          |      | Person 2 |  Phil |
| 3 |          |      | Person 3 | Steve |
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: See [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) for a formula to populate column B.

Comment: @Jeeped That is exactly what I was looking for thank you.